# Follow neighbors in a network using networkx

Tags: networkx, network-analysis

I have created a directed graph Network of nodes and edges using networkx.
It consists of bank transactions between bank accounts where every bank account is a node and the edges are created using the sending and the receiving account node. I have selected one node from all the network and I am trying to find all its neighbours that are sending to it using G.in_edges() function. From there I want to find its neighbors incoming neighbors and so on until there are no more neighbors. Example shown in the screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NdCS.png)

I have tried by writing the following code:

```
node_to_investigate = ['somenNodeName']
originalTransactions = {}
def scanNode(node_to_investigate):
    inEdges = G.in_edges(node_to_investigate)
    if len(inEdges) == 0:
        print('No incoming transactions')
        #return True
    else:
        for transaction in inEdges:
            if scanNode(findNode(transaction.data.v)):
                originalTransactions.add(transaction)
                print(originalTransactions)

final_node = scanNode(node_to_investigate)

print(final_node)
```

Comment: What happened with the code you tried? Incorrect results, exception raised,...? Can you provide an example with the desired output?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but I would try a network crawler approach in which you collect the incoming neighbors with a loop that stops when there are no more neighbors. Of course you'd need to register somewhere the nodes already passed in order to avoid loops in your passages across the network. Take account that for every node you analyse you can find N other incoming nodes and this can escalate quickly. Moreover, I don't know how your network is done, but I think that if it has a good connection you'll easily pass through the entire graph, making your analysis useless.